# Diplay MySQL results without reloading... AJAX is failing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having big troubles while trying to get the results of MySQL queries without reloading the page.
I've got 2 files : `index.php` and `action.php`

My queries work fine but AJAX will not work and I'm becoming mad while trying for hours and hours to load the result in the `.success` div without a reloading.

Thank you so much for your help!

**index.php**

```
//query SQL here then 

<form method="POST" name="form" id="form1">

    <select  name="province"> 
        <option>PROVINCE</option>
        <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $data['id_province']; ?>">
            <?php echo $data['province']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <select name="candidat">
        <option>CANDIDAT</option>
        <?php 
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['id_candidat']; ?>">
                <?php echo $data['pren1']; ?> <?php echo $data['nom_candidat']; ?></option>

                <?php
                    $id = $data['id_candidat'];
                    if ($id === $id) {
                        break;
                    }       
                } ?>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="ok" />

</form>
```

Then for displaying the results (in the same page)

```
<div id="success">
    <?php include("action.php"); ?> 
</div>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $province = $_POST['province']; 
    $candidat = $_POST['candidat']; 

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die ('Erreur : '.mysql_error() );;
    mysql_select_db("election");

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM resultat r, candidat c, province p, election e, prenom_cand t WHERE r.id_candidat = c.id_candidat AND t.id_prenom = c.id_prenom AND r.id_province = p.id_province  AND r.id_election = e.id_election AND e.id_election = 'PRES10'";

    $sql = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error()); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
    { 
        $score = $row->nbre_voix;
        $prenom = $row->pren1;
        $nom = $row->nom_candidat;
        $prov =  $row->province;
        $votes = $row->nbre_votants;
        $pourcent = ($score/$votes)*100;
        $nombre = number_format($pourcent, 2, ',', ' ');
        $nombre2 = number_format($pourcent, 0, ',', ' ');
        $id =  $row->id_province;
        $idc =  $row->id_candidat;              

        if ($province===$id && $candidat===$idc)
        {
            echo $prenom;
            echo " ";
            echo $nom;
            echo " a obtenu ";
            echo  $score; 
            echo " voix dans la province de ";
            echo $prov;
            echo ", soit une moyenne de ";
            echo $nombre;
            echo "%. <br/><br/>";   
            ?>

            <div style="width:<?php echo $nombre2 ?>%;background:#CCCCCC;height:40px;">
                <div style="padding:8px;">
                    <?php echo $nombre ?>%
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the poor Ajax placed between the head tags of index.php but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    cache: false
  }).done(function( response ) {
    alert( response );
    $(".success").html(response); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code of **index.php** will work? `<?php $id = $data['id_candidat']; if ($id === $id) {  break;  }  } ?>`. Notice that you are doing `if ($id === $id) {  break;  } `

Comment: Yes, my queries are right ! Everything is displaying very well. My only problem is with the reloading page each time that I click on the submit button !

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see wrong is

```
$(".success").html(response);
```

It should be

```
$("#success").html(response);
```

Secondly your action.php is looking for `$_POST` variables but you aren't sending any in your AJAX call. Because of `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` everything will be skipped, you need to do something like that:

```
$('.submit').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the form being submitted
    var province = $('#province').val(); // Don't forget to add the "province' id to your input 
    var candidate = $('#candidate').val(); // Don't forget to add "candidate' id to your input 
    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {submit: 1, province: province, candidate: candidate},
        beforeSend: function(){
           alert('Sending');
        },
        error: function(){
           alert('Error !');
        }, 
        success: function(){
           alert('Success !');
        } 
      }).done(function( response ) {
        alert( response );
        $("#success").html(response); 
      });

    }); 
});
```

Comment: I've tried and it didn't work. My page is still reloading. I don't understand why it doesn't want to do this. But hank you !

Comment: You need to trigger the ajax call when the submit button is clicked `$('.submit').on('click', function(){ [...] });` and use `preventDefault()` to keep it from submitting the form.

Comment: And be careful that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use PDO or mysqli_* not mysql_* it is obsolete as of PHP 5.5

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
preventDefault();

var province = $('#province').val(); // Add the "province' id to your input 
var candidat = $('#candidat').val(); // Add the "candidate' id to your input 

 $.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {submit: 1, province: province, candidat: candidat}
  }).done(function( response ) {
    alert( response );
    $(".success").html(response); 
  });

});  

});

Answer (score 0):

Use input type `button` Or Use submit with preventing its property to submit form , reload , So use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submit").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      data:$("#form1").serialize()
   }).done(function( response ) {
       alert( response );
   $("#success").html(response); 
  });
 });    
});
```

Here serializing form so you remove your headache whether I properly filled up data in `data` section or not etc.

Comment: preventDefault is blocking the display of the queries from action.php, so not solved but thank you

Comment: @laura123 , hi what is the actual issue ?

Comment: with preventDefault, the page doesn't reload but it's like it was blocked and the queries from action.php don't display in the "success" div

Comment: That is normal `preventDefault` keeps your form from being submitted normally so that you can send and receive data with AJAX instead. If something is wrong it is with your AJAX or the php script it is calling. Try looking up the doc on `$.ajax()` and its callback functions (I provided a few examples) and use your browser's debug tools / your logs or you are going to fumble around for hours.